# Customize toolbox in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How do I add a "Create Folder" action to the right-click menu in the toolbox?
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to add a tab by chance? Or maybe a folder to the project which is in the 'solution explorer'

Comment: In the project I add actions to the toolbox and I want to split them into categories (within the tab)

Comment: whay do you mena by categories  ? what is the type of this categories ? are they a user control developed by  you ?